# How can I disable/ignore html formatter for a few lines in Visual Studio Code 2022?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to prevent the formatting of section of an html file in Visual Studio Code 2022.
I tried adding some comments tags above and, above and below... but nothing seems to help...
It keeps formatting the entire file.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible with the default formatter, but it's easily achievable with [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) - using the `<!-- prettier-ignore -->` skips formatting on the element directly after that.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head></head>

  <body>
    <div>Some div here that will be formatted normally</div>
    <!-- prettier-ignore -->
    <div>Some other div here that will be left as is</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

For this to work you have to set Prettier as the default formatter for HTML:

```json
"[html]": {
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
}
```

Reference: https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html

Answer (score 1):

For the default vscode formatter you can specify an unformatted content delimiter:

in settings.json:

```
"html.format.unformattedContentDelimiter": "<!--noformat-->",
```

in *.html file:

```
<body>
    <!--noformat-->
    <div       id="container"         style="width:800px;height:600px;border:1px solid #ccc"></div>
    <!--noformat-->
</body>
```

Reference: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/139617#issuecomment-1003738321