How do I get VSCode to format Golang Templates as I want
I am just learning Golang templating. I am trying to use blocks. VS Code or gopls is formatting my blocks in a very unreadable way.
I want to define a number of blocks in a single HTML file (index.html). When I save the file VS Code is reformatting to this {{ block "one" . }} . . . {{ end }} {{ block "two" . }} . . . {{ end }}
I want the format to be:
{{ block "one" . }} . . . {{ end }} 

{{ block "two" . }} . . . {{ end }}

I have tried the following VS Code settings:
  "[go]": {
    "editor.insertSpaces": false,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.organizeImports": "always"
    }
  }

  "[go]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "golang.go",
    "editor.insertSpaces": false,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.organizeImports": "always"
    }
  }

  "[go]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "golang.go",
    "editor.insertSpaces": false,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.organizeImports": "always"
    }
  },
  "gopls": {
      "formatting.gofumpt": true
  },

  "[go]": {
    "editor.insertSpaces": false,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.organizeImports": "always"
    }
  },
  "gopls": {
      "formatting.gofumpt": true
  },

None of these settings change the behavior. I have reloaded the VS Code window with every setting change.

You change things for Go Files, your Templates is html so could it be you have a html formatter that do this ? Last Resort is to disable formatOnSave for HTML

There is formatting enabled for Golang & HTML, both of which work as expected and as I prefer. It is just when using the templating syntax that things go sideways.

Yeah but you Show only golang specific settings in questions, so either you find a custom html formatter option for ninja like codeblocks or add a "no format" thingy so formatter does not change this code like described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74529552/how-can-i-disable-ignore-html-formatter-for-a-few-lines-in-visual-studio-code-20

Ah, gotcha. I misread your comment. I see what you're saying. I'll repost here if I find a solution that does what I want.
